# hover with a nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

i was wondering if it is possible to use a hover with a nth-child like so

```
#gallery a img:hover {
    display: block;
    height:300px;
    width:450px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    margin-left:-112.5px;
    margin-top:-75px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
```

From this up here to some thing like this down here, only its not working

```
 #gallery a img:hover:nth-child(1n+4) {
        display: block;
        height:300px;
        width:450px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:99;
        margin-left:-112.5px;
        margin-top:-75px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    }
```

Comment: have you tried it? You can use jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes i tried in on my one script it just wont work

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Anyone who has the same problem: Please note that in my case I'd mistakenly used `a::hover:nth-child()` instead of `a:hover:nth-child()`(notice to use only one `:` for hover) and it works fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#gallery a:hover:nth-child(1n+4)
```

Will work correctly but style the A tags instead of the IMG inside.

When you have markup like...

```
<a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
<a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
<a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
<a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
<a href="#"><img src=""/></a>
```

You cannot select the inner IMG and then try to apply an nth-child on it because there is only 1 IMG inside of the A tag.

Refer to the JSFIDDLE I created http://jsfiddle.net/fXS93/2/

Any change in how the IMG markup is wrapped will reset the CSS matching and NTH-CHILD calculation. This applies even if you are matching on a CLASS that all of the IMG share.

This is true for the latest FF, Chrome, and IE9.

Comment: thanks a lot, `li:hover:nth-child` works, where`li:nth-child :hover` not works

Answer (score 0):

in which browser did you tried this?
and on how many elements did you run the formula?
it will run from the third element in your parent element **AND**
you should add      `:hover`
after the nth-child like this:`:nth-child(1n+4):hover`
although it wont work in IE8 or earlier
**EDIT:**
i tried and the order did not affect the result you can put `:hover` before the `:nthchild()`

Comment: The order does not matter.

Comment: I have tried it in w3schools tryit editor for `nth-child` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even)  and yes the order does not matter but the browser and elements quantity does matter if there is less than 4 target elements you can not see the result when mouse hover on them

Comment: Yeah I said the order does not matter.